# Is Firebase efficient in 'Group By' operations?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, group-by, denormalization

I am trying to adapt my normalized datamodel, to a Firebase-friendly datamodel.
My application primarily runs 'summary queries' on the normalised tables e.g. things analogous to:

'*SELECT ctryid, avg(age) FROM users GROUP BY ctryid*'

Having an integer ctryid speeds things up tremendously,
and in my mind it's because he has to compare an integer ctryid, instead of strings (USA, FRA, ITA, ...).
Now I learned that Firebase generates keys like 'Xj34Fhe2sP0'. Would that indeed imply less efficiency as compared to my SQL queries?

What would such a query look like in Firebase? I do not wish to denormalize any calculated results.

Edit: Denormalizing for avoiding costly joins, would imply also including **ctryname** in the users object right?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support group-by clauses in its queries, nor any other aggregation operations. I don't think the keys that it generates are very important though.

---

What I often recommend is that you model your database to reflect what you show in the screens of your app. So your SQL queries seems to delivery a list of country IDs with the average age of the users in each country ID.

If that's what you want to show, consider storing exactly that data in Firebase:

```
averageAgeByCountryId: {
 "NL": 43.3,
 "US": 38.1
}
```

---

Not to write this data you'll need to update the existing average each time you write a new user to a country. To allow that you'll probably want to instead store the total number of users in each country, and their total age:

```
averageAgeByCountryId: {
 "NL": { userCount: 5, sumOfAge: 217 },
 "US": { userCount: 10, sumOfAge: 381 }
}
```

Now you can still easily calculate the average age, but in this format it is also easier to update the average ages as you add users.

Comment: Much helpful, thx!

Comment: Calculation itself would then be done client-side?

Comment: It can be done client-side (and then secured through [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)) or with a server-side listener or triggered Cloud Function.